# Formatting Chart Data for Node Red

Tags: node-red

This is first attempt at getting node-red to take in historical information and display is in a line chart. 
The information I get is shown below, a series of values in array of time and value.

The information below is the raw data I get from my HTTP GET command. I then pass this information to my function block to try format the data to view in a chart.

[{"x":"1525158700957","y":"4.77"},{"x":"1525158701981","y":"5.90"},    {"x":"1525158702985","y":"7.03"},{"x":"1525158704017","y":"8.18"},    {"x":"1525158705041","y":"9.31"},{"x":"1525158706062","y":"10.45"},{"x":"1525158707089","y":"11.58"},{"x":"1525158708095","y":"12.71"},{"x":"1525158709121","y":"13.84"},{"x":"1525158710143","y":"14.98"},{"x":"1525158711171","y":"16.11"},{"x":"1525158712178","y":"17.24"},{"x":"1525158713203","y":"18.37"},{"x":"1525158714206","y":"19.50"},{"x":"1525158715230","y":"20.63"},{"x":"1525158716251","y":"21.77"},{"x":"1525158717270","y":"22.90"},{"x":"1525158718291","y":"24.03"},{"x":"1525158719315","y":"25.17"},{"x":"1525158720345","y":"26.32"},{"x":"1525158721370","y":"27.45"},{"x":"1525158722392","y":"28.59"},{"x":"1525158723424","y":"29.74"},{"x":"1525158724445","y":"30.87"},{"x":"1525158725468","y":"32.00"},{"x":"1525158726474","y":"33.13"},{"x":"1525158727501","y":"34.27"},{"x":"1525158728528","y":"35.40"},{"x":"1525158729532","y":"36.53"},{"x":"1525158730572","y":"37.66"},{"x":"1525158731569","y":"38.78"},{"x":"1525158732592","y":"39.91"},{"x":"1525158733599","y":"41.04"},{"x":"1525158734624","y":"42.17"},{"x":"1525158735644","y":"43.32"},{"x":"1525158736670","y":"44.44"},{"x":"1525158737673","y":"45.57"},{"x":"1525158738706","y":"46.70"},{"x":"1525158739714","y":"47.83"},{"x":"1525158740737","y":"48.98"},{"x":"1525158741763","y":"50.10"},{"x":"1525158742782","y":"51.25"},{"x":"1525158743803","y":"52.38"},{"x":"1525158744826","y":"53.51"},{"x":"1525158745830","y":"54.64"},{"x":"1525158746854","y":"55.76"},{"x":"1525158747876","y":"56.91"},{"x":"1525158748897","y":"58.04"},{"x":"1525158749921","y":"59.17"},{"x":"1525158750924","y":"60.30"},{"x":"1525158751946","y":"61.42"},{"x":"1525158752973","y":"62.57"},{"x":"1525158753993","y":"63.70"},{"x":"1525158755016","y":"64.84"},{"x":"1525158756039","y":"65.97"},{"x":"1525158757064","y":"67.12"},{"x":"1525158758091","y":"68.25"},{"x":"1525158759103","y":"69.38"},{"x":"1525158760127","y":"70.52"},{"x":"1525158761151","y":"71.65"},{"x":"1525158762173","y":"72.80"},{"x":"1525158763198","y":"73.92"},{"x":"1525158764204","y":"75.05"},{"x":"1525158765228","y":"76.18"},{"x":"1525158766251","y":"77.33"},{"x":"1525158767276","y":"78.45"},{"x":"1525158768300","y":"79.60"},{"x":"1525158769324","y":"80.73"},{"x":"1525158770356","y":"81.86"}]

I have been trying to take this information, around 100 record, and show the on a graph. The documentation suggests that data needs to be in the format;

```
[{
"series": ["A", "B", "C"],
"data": [
[{ "x": 1504029632890, "y": 5 },
{ "x": 1504029636001, "y": 4 },
{ "x": 1504029638656, "y": 2 }
],
[{ "x": 1504029633514, "y": 6 },
{ "x": 1504029636622, "y": 7 },
{ "x": 1504029639539, "y": 6 }
],
[{ "x": 1504029634400, "y": 7 },
{ "x": 1504029637959, "y": 7 },
{ "x": 1504029640317, "y": 7 }
]
],
"labels": [""]  
}]
```

I have tried to add the 'series' and 'data' element with a function block, like this;

```
m = msg.payload;
var output = {labels: ["Temperature"], series: ["B"], data:[m]};
return {payload:[output]};
```

When the information in processed by my function block, I do not get any errors in the Pi Console. On the Dashboard, the Chart Axis are drawn with the current timestamp only, and no other data.

And this is the results.

```
[{"labels":["Temperature"],"series":["B"],"data":["   [{\"x\":\"1525160264800\",\"y\":\"42.38\"},{\"x\":\"1525160265824\",\"y\":\"43.51\"},{\"x\":\"1525160266829\",\"y\":\"44.64\"},{\"x\":\"1525160267852\",\"y\":\"45.76\"},{\"x\":\"1525160268872\",\"y\":\"46.89\"},{\"x\":\"1525160269892\",\"y\":\"48.04\"},{\"x\":\"1525160270913\",\"y\":\"49.17\"},{\"x\":\"1525160271936\",\"y\":\"50.30\"},{\"x\":\"1525160272941\",\"y\":\"51.42\"},{\"x\":\"1525160273962\",\"y\":\"52.55\"},{\"x\":\"1525160274969\",\"y\":\"53.68\"},{\"x\":\"1525160275995\",\"y\":\"54.81\"},{\"x\":\"1525160277003\",\"y\":\"55.94\"},{\"x\":\"1525160278024\",\"y\":\"57.07\"},{\"x\":\"1525160279037\",\"y\":\"58.19\"},{\"x\":\"1525160280063\",\"y\":\"59.34\"},{\"x\":\"1525160281085\",\"y\":\"60.47\"},{\"x\":\"1525160282104\",\"y\":\"61.60\"},{\"x\":\"1525160283129\",\"y\":\"62.74\"},{\"x\":\"1525160284157\",\"y\":\"63.89\"},{\"x\":\"1525160285179\",\"y\":\"65.02\"},{\"x\":\"1525160286206\",\"y\":\"66.16\"},{\"x\":\"1525160287243\",\"y\":\"67.29\"},{\"x\":\"1525160288250\",\"y\":\"68.44\"},{\"x\":\"1525160289270\",\"y\":\"69.57\"},{\"x\":\"1525160290295\",\"y\":\"70.69\"},{\"x\":\"1525160291301\",\"y\":\"71.82\"},{\"x\":\"1525160292329\",\"y\":\"72.97\"},{\"x\":\"1525160293350\",\"y\":\"74.10\"},{\"x\":\"1525160..."]}]
```

As you can tell I don't know JavaScript and looking for a few tips on how to take the original source to show in graph.

Many thanks for your help.

Richard

Comment: Richard - it looks like you are on the right track... but when you say it "fails miserably", that doesn't help us make suggestions on what needs to be changed. Does anything appear on the graph? Any error messages in node-red or the console logs? Please update the question with the actual `msg.payload` data copied from the debug sidebar -- I'm sure there is a simpler way using a `change` node and JSONata expression, but it helps to have the actual JSON data.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment. I have added the Payload to the original question.

Comment: If you are looking for another way to format the **query output**, I'll need that raw data, not the output from your function code... Also, it looks like you've just copied/pasted the payload from the display in the debug sidebar -- which is not valid json formatted text. Instead, when you hover the mouse over the object, you'll see some little buttons pop up on the right... click the second one to "copy the value" and update this question, please.

Comment: Also, please add more detail about **how** it fails -- does the graph show up? Is any data showing? Any errors in the browser console or node-red console log?

Comment: SteveR, thanks for your patience and time with this. Richard

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I see the issue you are having now... thanks for updating the question with the raw outputs.

Your function looks to be doing exactly what it needs to do, which is to embed the entire result set into the payload using (essentially) this javascript expression:

```
var output = {labels: ["Temperature"], series: ["B"], data:[msg.payload]};
```

Since your query already returns an array of objects with x/y data points, this wraps the data in an array, as is necessary for loading all the data into the chart. **However**, as you can see there are lots of escaped quotes in the payload you are building -- this means that the incoming msg.payload is NOT an array of objects, but a JSON string. You should be able to see the datatype (i.e. "string", not "object") in your raw query output debug node. So did you wire your query results to a JSON node? If so, it may be changing your query array of objects into a JSON string -- if not, simply add a JSON node to convert the resulting string into a Javascript array of objects. Either way, verify that the msg.payload is an array of objects before being passed into your function.

Now, if you are feeling adventurous, you can replace your function node with a `change` node -- use the pulldown to select the `J:` option (for JSONata mode), and "Set" `msg.`payload to this expression:

```
[
    {
        "series": ["B"],
        "labels": ["Temperature"],
        "data": [
            [payload.{
                "x": $number(x),
                "y": $number(y)
            }]
        ]
    }
]
```

This kind of JSONata expression is what I normally use to restructure javascript data into whatever format I need for charts and graphs. It also coerces your string data into numbers (which may or may not be necessary).

You may want to [learn more about the JSONata](http://jsonata.org/) syntax, as it's very powerful, although quite different from Javascript (actually, it's similar to using XPath for XML manipulation, but works on JSON data). The site also has an exerciser that you can use to build expression against your own data -- in fact, here is the page I used to [format your result data](http://try.jsonata.org/S1GKmbL6M). A similar "tester" is also built into the change node properties panel:

[image: change node jsonata tester]

In either tool, you can see the output data change as you type your expression -- very handy!

Comment: Steve, I understand where the problem is, and with the help of JSONata, I can compare my function block payload. Very helpful!! JSONata is certainly the way forward. Many thanks for your help. Richard

Comment: Glad I could help -- and also convert another person to using JSONata! It's not for everything, but it is well worth learning. Please remember to vote for this answer and accept it as correct, if it solves your problem.